# Linear Systems: Differential Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

The book being used for the course is *Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems* by Lawrence Perko.

The question is as follows:

> > Find the general solution of the linear system (**x$^{'}$**=$A$**x**) when $A$ is the $n \times n$ diagonal matrix $A = $ diag$[\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_n]$. What condition on the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$ will guarantee that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}$**x**$(t) = 0$ for all solutions **x**(t) of **x$^{'}$**=$A$**x**.

If I understand correctly:

The general solution to the linear system:

\begin{eqnarray}
x_1(t) & = & c_1\exp{\lambda_1 t}\\
x_2(t) & = & c_2\exp{\lambda_2 t}\\
&\vdots&\\
x_n(t) & = & c_n\exp{\lambda_n t}
\end{eqnarray}

And the condition on the eigenvalues ($\lambda$) that will guarantee that each $x_i$ will converge to $0$ is when all eigenvalues are negative: $\lambda_i < 0$.

---

Part of me things I am missing something. I could just be me being to paranoid. Thank you for your time and thank you in advance for any feedback you may give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the real part of all eigenvalues has to be negative, but everything else seems right. ..